# Can't check if variable is null without getting internal error 500

Tags: javascript, smarty

An object displays as null in the console:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("id"+"{$id_attribute}"));
```

gives `null`. 
Edit : {$id_attribute} is smarty (server language) and this is coded in a .tpl file.
But then I try to check if it is null like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("id"+"{$id_attribute}") == null) {
    alert('something wrong');
}
```

and I get an internal error 500 and my page doesn't display correctly....

Any idea on what I did wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: is there a server side language here? what is `{$id_attribute}` doing? you've only tagged javascript on the question. i don't think it's even possible for javascript to cause a 500, as that is a response from a server.

Comment: Internal Error 500 comes from the server side code. You're showing us client side code.

Comment: Agreed - {$id_attribute} is not part of JavaScript, therefore it is likely your server-side code that's causing this error.

Comment: Looks like you have some PHP syntax in there...

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers or just IE ?

Comment: I don't have IE, but it's happening in firefox and chrome